# Автоматическая подстановка пароля SSH в CMD Win10

Tags: cmd, windows-10, powershell

Чтобы сразу логинится по SSH в Putty я создавал ярлык и в свойствах писал `user@ip -pw password`. Могу ли я что-то подобное сделать со стандартной `cmd` оболочкой в Windows? Я попробовал `ssh user@ip`, но он требует введение пароля в консоли, пробовал добавить теги `-p`, `-pw`, но они не помогают. Подскажите, как можно сделать автоматическую подстановку пароля в ярлыке `cmd` при SSH подключении

Comment: Лучше перейдите на использование SSH-ключей

Comment: @andreymal я понимаю, но заказчик именно так сделал, тут я не в силах его переубеждать

Comment: Или костыли, типа `autoit!` или публичный\приватный ключ.

Comment: так и продолжайте запускать pytty из cmd

Comment: @user7860670 да, конечно пока не нашел способа приходится через putty, но интересно, можно ли тоже самое через стандартную консоль сделать

Comment: если нет возможности использовать ключи, попробуйте использовать `|`, что-то в виде `echo <mypwd> | ssh user@ip`

Comment: @IvanIgnatiev выдает ошибку `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`

Comment: @RoyalGoose [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal) советуют добавить `-tt` - `ssh -tt user@ip`

Comment: @IvanIgnatiev не знаю как это работает, но при добавлении -tt и echo командная строка открывается и сразу же закрывается. Добавление `pause` и `\k cmd` не помогает